# Unhandled exception at GLfloat

Tags: c++, unhandled-exception

I am trying to run the triangle.cpp project (the first one) in the OpenGL SuperBible 5th. edition. I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express. I can compile and build the project but when I try to run it I get an unhandled exception at the line marked with 12 asterisks in the code below. I would be very grateful for help solving this!!

```
void SetupRC()
{
    // Blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
    shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();

    // Load up a triangle
    GLfloat vVerts[9] = { -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f,
                           0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f }; //************ 

   triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 3);
   triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vVerts);
   triangleBatch.End();
}
```

Comment: You stated that you get an `Unhandled Exception`. What did it say, exactly?

Comment: It says: Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in Triangle.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000. The following is the output from the debugger.

Comment: 'Triangle.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\opengl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Triangle.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Triangle.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Triangle.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Triangle.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\secur32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Triangle.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

Comment: You know if it points to that line it might well be that `InitializeStockShaders` failed.

Comment: If InitializeStockShaders failed do you know how I could fix that?